# Travis CI and renamed github account

Tags: github, travis-ci

I just renamed my github account, and github sets up forwarding for the new account from all the old URLs, which is great. Travis seems to benefit from this: My list of repositories in Travis showed all my repositories under their old name initially. I would like them to show under the new name, though. So I hit the "Sync" button on the repositories page, and now I have no repositories, and the message: "Sorry, it seems like we couldn't find any repositories you have access to on GitHub."

How can I fix this? Do I have to create a new Travis account?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the answer was to log out of Travis, then log in with my github credentials again. Everything is A-OK now.